# Jenkins Groovy with XMLSlurper Error "failed to serialize"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, xmlslurper

I am on Jenksin 2.46.2 and have a job that uses Active Choices Reactive Parameter. I select my servers in my first selection from a XML file using XMLSlurper and reference that for my second selection.  When I hardcode the server name the code works fine.  When I use the variable in my code I get an error.

This code works:

```
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("/app/jenkins/jobs/servers.xml")
def SERVER = 'testserver1'
def output = []
serverList.Server.find { it.@name == SERVER}.CleanUp.GZIP.File.each{ 
    it.output.add(p)
}

return output
```

When I reference the variable selection from my previous selection I get the error:

```
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("/app/jenkins/jobs/servers.xml")
def SERVER = SERVER
def output = []
serverList.Server.find { it.@name == SERVER}.CleanUp.GZIP.File.each{ 
    it.output.add(p)
}

return output
```

The error that I am getting is below. Any idea why I get an error?

```
WARNING: failed to serialize [[/app/test2/log], [/app/test2/log]] for ...*other text*... net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!
```

Here is my XML file:

```xml
<ServerList>
  <Server name="testserver1">
      <CleanUP>
        <GZIP>
          <File KeepDays="30">/app/test1/log</File>
        </GZIP>
      </CleanUP>
    </Server>  
  <Server name="testserver2">
    <CleanUP>
      <GZIP>
        <File KeepDays="30">/app/test2/log</File>
      </GZIP>
    </CleanUP>
  </Server>
</ServerList>
```

NE.jpg

Comment: what is the desired output? both `log`'s?

Comment: Thank you.....the result should show:
/app/test1/log

Comment: But you said, it is already working if you use `testserver1`, Then what is criteria for change you were trying? what do you mean by `I reference the variable selection from my previous selection I get the error:`?

Comment: What are you passing in the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script that you need, which reads the value of File element and returns a list:

```
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("/app/jenkins/jobs/servers.xml")
return serverList.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'File'}*.text()
```

Output:

```
[/app/test1/log, /app/test2/log]
```

**EDIT: based on OP comments**

```
def server = 'testserver1'
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("/app/jenkins/jobs/servers.xml")
def result = serverList.'**'.find{ it.@name == server}.CleanUP.GZIP.File
println result
return result
```

EDIT2:

If you want list or array, try below:

```
def server = 'testserver1'
def serverList = new XmlSlurper().parse("/app/jenkins/jobs/servers.xml")
def result = serverList.'**'.findAll{ it.@name == server}*.CleanUP.GZIP.File.text()
println result
return result
```

Comment: @RyanJohnson, did the above helped? If not can you clarify what is needed?

Comment: @RyanJohnson, do you just want value of file for matching `testserver1`?which will be single value not a list.

Comment: I think my issue is with my code to build my array of servers.  I am trying to put the code in here but it is not pasting it nicely.  My output should be ['testserver1','testserver2'].....

def output = []
serverList.Server.findAll {output.add(it.@name)}

return output

Comment: @RyanJohnson, can you please check the edit part of the answer and see if that is helpful? check the demo [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/6323578999930880)

Comment: I removed all my other code and I do see the "failed to serialize" error on my code around getting the servers.  So maybe the issue is with that code causing issues with other code.

Comment: @RyanJohnson, have you checked the demo link from the previous comment? Is that what you are looking for? Is it showing desired output?

Comment: I tried that but it did not work yet....thank you for your assistance.  I need the values to be in an array because they are going into a dropdown box where someone can select a value.  I was not sure how to modify that code so the return values are in an array.

Comment: @RyanJohnson, if you are expecting array, check `EDIT2`. Just need to use `findAll`.